# Improving distribution array element distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a command in Python that would calculate the distribution.
For an example the call:

```
n=10
x = [1]*3 # returns [1,1,1]
y = [s/sum(a)*n for s in x] # returns [3.3,3.3,3.3]
```

The problem is that this way, the program I am using would round down the values to 3 and basically, the sum of the array would be 9 instead of 10. How could I improve the call so that I get whole values like `[4.0,3.0,3.0]`?

Comment: Did you mean `sum(x)`? `a` is undefined/

Comment: Also, how would you decide which element to add `1` to? Is `[3, 4, 3]` an acceptable answer?

Comment: I am quite flexible about where the extra element would go to so '[3,4,3]' is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to find which elements to round up while rounding all the rest down. One way to decide is that the element with the largest fractional part gets rounded up but no element is rounded up more than once.

```py
import numpy as np

def distribute(weights, total):
    # calculate the distribution as you have done
    dist = np.array(weights) / sum(weights) * total

    # separate the fractional parts
    fracs, dist = np.modf(dist)

    # adjust if necessary
    while dist.sum() != total:
        # find the index of the maximum value of the fractional parts
        max_idx = np.argmax(fracs)

        # increment just that one value
        dist[max_idx] += 1

        # zero out that fractional part so we don't use it twice
        fracs[max_idx] = 0

    return dist


>>> distribute([1]*3, 10)
array([4., 3., 3.])

>>> distribute([1, 2, 3], 16)
array([3., 5., 8.])

>>> distribute([1, 2, 3, 1, 1], 21)
array([3., 5., 8., 3., 2.])
```